# What are centripetal forces for flywheel precession movement?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, centripetal-force, rigid-body-dynamics, precession

[image]

What are centripetal forces for this flywheel? I suppose for rotation around "inner" axis centripetal force is due to attractive forces between particles inside flywheel. However what about rotation around outer axis? Static friction? If yes, why its direction is centripetal and not centrifugal, when G-force has tendency to rotate flywheel clockwise with respect to point of contact with ground?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The force $G\sin(\theta)$ creates a torque that, on its own, would tend to rotate *the spinning axis* about the point where the top touches the table. This adds a torque to an object that already has significant angular momentum. This added torque, by $\tau = d ~ G\sin = J \vec{\alpha}$ adds it’s angular momentum, $M$ in the figure, by the right hand rule of $\vec{d} \times \vec{G}$. That $M$ is being added the existing angular momentum vector $L$. The vector sum moves $L$ to $L+dL$ as shown. **But the direction of $M$ keeps changing**. So even though there is an apparent rotation in the precession motion, it is part of a larger $\omega$. It does not need a centripetal force because it is not a simple revolution (in fact we just analyzed the changing angular momentum vector). That provides the precession. And $M$ will continue to result in the tangential motion as shown.

One way to (very loosely) think of it is that the gyroscopic force is providing the centripetal resistance. But the above description is more rigorous as we can see how the momentum vectors add. To gain better intuition, see this and related about precession and/or gyroscopes:  https://youtu.be/ty9QSiVC2g0

Comment: I see, so in fact centripetal force requirement for circular motion is, let's say just for constant direction of torque; when direction of torque is changing we do not need centripetal force and we use second impulse law (dL/dt=M), right ? In that case, also turning motocycle by leaning does not require centripetal force by static friction, right ? However in car centripetal force by static friction is needed to make a turn, because this effect is somehow cancel out (I suppose, cause of two turning tires with weight in the middle), right ?

Comment: Ok, Thank you very much. It helps a lot.

Comment: Hello @Al Brown again. I was searching something more about cycles dynamics. Everywhere (for example here http://www.svecw.edu.in/Docs%5CMEDMLNotes2013.pdf ) were friction forces involved in turning of cycle (see page 31 - different frame so they have centrifugal...) making centripetal force (part of ?). Should we considered them as additional terms to mentioned gyroscopic effect ? If yes, what is different from our original flywheel ? I'm thinking about different spinning axis, but still, applying the same approach should not be friction involved in CENTRIFUGAL direction for our flywheel ?

Comment: Interesting. I dont know for certain. But im thinking that since other applications, including especially cycling, have an actual curved path for the whole object. The top may have a little of that type of travel if the tip travels a circle, but the precessing itself is not so much the top going in a circle (it’s point on the ground moving) as it is leaning in a circle, which can only be gyroscopic force(?). I guess if we focus on the circular path of the point, then yes that requires friction to mai

Comment: ntain the arc ⟹ centripetal (and hence centrifugal) force. I guess I agree. But is important that it doesn’t cover the leaning/precessing aspect of the circle of the com. (If I had more time I would’ve written a shorter reply)

Comment: It makes sense. Precession does not require centripetal force as whole object is in fact not moving in circle. I totally agree and now I can understand that, also I understand that as whole object (cycle) moves in circle, then must have centripetal force (friction). OK, but now what actually makes difference ? I suppose it is, cause top is force on just spinning object, but in cycle case is it torque in fact not on just spinnig, but on rolling object (I mean tires of course). Just think about one rolling wheel, it also has translational velocity I suppose.